# Scroll SearchResponse not iterable when there are less results than the scrollSize setting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a loop like this...

```
while (true) {
    scrollResp = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId()).setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();

    for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits()){
        // does this when totalHits > scrollSize, skips it otherwise
    }

    //Break condition: No hits are returned
    if (scrollResp.hits().hits().length == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The scrollSize of the query is set to 500.  When the scrollResp.getHits().totalHits() < 500 the for loop is never entered.  If I modify the scrollSize to be < totalHits the for loop will be entered.

In general I am expecting > 500 results per query, but I need it to work in either case.  Not sure if possibly I am attempting the iteration incorrectly or what.  Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do something like this:

```
    // tested also with pageSize = 1
    final int pageSize = 100;
    SearchResponse firstScrollResponse = client
            .prepareSearch("db")
            .setTypes("collection")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1))
            .setSize(pageSize)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();

    //get the first page of actual results
    firstScrollResponse = client.prepareSearchScroll(firstScrollResponse.getScrollId())
                                  .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1))
                                  .execute()
                                  .actionGet();

    while (firstScrollResponse.getHits().hits().length > 0) {

        for (final SearchHit hit : firstScrollResponse.getHits().hits()) {
            // do smth with it
        }

        // update the scroll response to get more entries from the old index
        firstScrollResponse = client.prepareSearchScroll(firstScrollResponse.getScrollId())
                                      .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1))
                                      .execute()
                                      .actionGet();
    }
```

The trick is first get the first page of actual results from the scroll, since the first search response contains no hits.