# Getting no. of hits to be Zero even when total hits is non-zero value

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Java API for sending search requests. 
`System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().totalHits());` gives me a non-zero number which I confirmed is correct as I checked it on Sense as well. But as soon as try to run a loop on the hits like `for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {...}` or try to access the hits individually `searchResponse.getHits().getAt(0).getSource().get("doc_id");` I get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I have a list of ~10000 terms for whom I have to do an individual search. The first term gives the answer but for the second term I get the number of hits as some non-zero number but the `SearchHits` is empty!

```
public Tuple2<Set<String>, String> getUnstemmedTerms(String indexName, String stem) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Integer> unstemmed = new HashMap<>();
        SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = client.getClient().prepareSearch(indexName)
                .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                .setQuery(QueryStem(stem))
                .setSize(10);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

        while(true) {
            searchResponse = client.getClient()
                    .prepareSearchScroll(searchResponse.getScrollId())
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();
            System.out.println(searchResponse.getHits().totalHits()); // gives 3
            searchResponse.getHits().getAt(0).getSource().get("doc_id"); // gives java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

            for (SearchHit hit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
            // Do some stuff
            }       
            if (searchResponse.getHits().hits().length == 0)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(unstemmed.size()); // gives 0
        return new Tuple2<>(unstemmed.keySet(), term);
    }
```

I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: can you include more code?

Comment: @depperm I have added some code

Comment: You overwrite `searchResponse` with `client.getClient()...`

Comment: @JoopEggen I could not understand your point.

Comment: Sorry, talked nonsense, however see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239537/scroll-searchresponse-not-iterable-when-there-are-less-results-than-the-scrollsi